# org-mode outline level specific fill-column values

Tags: emacs, org-mode, word-wrap

I was wondering if it is possible to set different fill-column values for different levels of the outline. Currently I set it at 78, and it seems how the column is counted is different for for lower levels (), and as a results, texts for lower levels go over 78 column.

The same question was asked in the mailing list, but there were no replies:
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-05/msg00654.html

Best,
Joon

Comment: `fill-column` should apply equally to all levels, so if you find it not be applied correctly in lower levels, you might want to report it as a bug.

Comment: It is correctly applied - it's just that the starting column for lower level is different. For example, for the second level, column 0 is actually column 5 in the editor window - so column 78 is column 83 and it goes over to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I added functions to calculate apt offsets and call regular org fill stuff:

```
(defun calc-offset-on-org-level ()
  "Calculate offset (in chars) on current level in org mode file."
  (* (or (org-current-level) 0) org-indent-indentation-per-level))

(defun my-org-fill-paragraph (&optional JUSTIFY)
  "Calculate apt fill-column value and fill paragraph."
  (let* ((fill-column (- fill-column (calc-offset-on-org-level))))
    (org-fill-paragraph JUSTIFY)))

(defun my-org-auto-fill-function ()
  "Calculate apt fill-column value and do auto-fill"
  (let* ((fill-column (- fill-column (calc-offset-on-org-level))))
    (org-auto-fill-function)))
```

And set up org-mode in my .emacs to use this functions (see org.el, org-setup-filling):

```
(defun my-org-mode-hook ()
  (setq fill-paragraph-function   'my-org-fill-paragraph
        normal-auto-fill-function 'my-org-auto-fill-function)

(add-hook 'org-load-hook 'my-org-mode-hook)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-hook)
```

As result i got (wysiwyg):

```
* Top level heading
  This is sufficiently long string, and, as you see fill-column is not far
  from screen edge on the top level.  My fill-column value is 77.

        * Level 5
          Offset is 12 chars on this level, but we set there fill column to
          the 78 - 12 = 66 chars.

                                  * Derived 18 (?)
                                    Auto fill mode works too due to function
                                    my-org-auto-fill-function.
```